# How to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException when using spring-data-neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have a simple test project where checking spring-data-neo4j with spring boot version: 2.1.0.RELEASE (https://github.com/tomkasp/neo4j-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/athleticspot/neo4jplayground/domain/AthleteRepository.java)

spring-data-neo4j (version: 5.1.4.RELEASE) dependency is injected by spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j.

My goal was to create a repository method which fetches data with containing and ingnorecase functionalities. In order to do that I've created below method within repository:

```
public interface AthleteRepository extends CrudRepository<Athlete, Long> {

    List<Athlete> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);

}
```

When I run above functions I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to ignore case of java.lang.String types, the property 'name' must reference a String
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.filter.PropertyComparisonBuilder.applyCaseInsensitivityIfShouldIgnoreCase(PropertyComparisonBuilder.java:101) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
```

Doesn't spring-data-neo4j support Containing and IgnoreCase together? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: It is already been added to the feature set (and solved)  for the Moore release train https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it seems not possible because the referenced `org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.filter.PropertyComparisonBuilder` seems to allow ignoring case only for "SIMPLE_PROERTY" (is, or equals). See method `canIgnoreCase` in same class:

```
private boolean canIgnoreCase(Part part) {
    return part.getType() == SIMPLE_PROPERTY && String.class.equals(part.getProperty().getLeafType());
}
```

Fix is coming with spring 5.2 (Moore): https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-1190

Comment: Thanks, that make sens